# Aurelia: not recognizing feature module

Tags: aurelia

I just discovered this framework and I was loving it so far. But then I tried to create a feature module and for some reason it's not working.

I created a new Aurelia app using the CLI:

```
au new
```

Then I started coding, created an HTML-only custom element and used it, it worked great.

The problem came when I wanted to create a feature module.

First, this is my `src` folder (yeah, I'm going with a classic todo-list app):

[image: src folder]

So, in the `main.js` file I've declared the todo feature module:

```
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';
import * as environment from '../config/environment.json';
import {PLATFORM} from 'aurelia-pal';

export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .feature(PLATFORM.moduleName('todo/index'));

  aurelia.use.developmentLogging(environment.debug ? 'debug' : 'warn');

  if (environment.testing) {
    aurelia.use.plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-testing'));
  }

  aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName('app')));
}
```

Now, depending on what I do I get one error or another.

### Option 1

If I configure `todo/index.js` as a module like this:

```
export function configure(config) {
  config.globalResources(['./todo-list', './todo-item']);
}
```

Then I get this warning and the web goes blank:

[image: Warning message and blank page]

### Option 2

If I comment out the `config.globalResources()` line in `todo/index.js` then I don't get the warning, the page seems to work. But when I click on the button to add a new Todo item I get an error that the function doesn't exist.

In `app.html` I import `todo/todo-list.html`:

```
<template>
  <require from="./app-header.html"></require>
  <require from="./todo/todo-list.html"></require>

  <app-header></app-header>

  <main>
    <todo-list></todo-list>
  </main>
</template>
```

And this is the content of `todo-list.html`:

```
<template>
  <form>
    <label for="item-text">Añadir elemento: </label>
    <input id="item-text" value.bind="newTodo"/>
    <button type="button" click.trigger="addTodo()">Añadir</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

This is `todo-list.js`:

```
import {TodoItem} from './todo-item';

export class TodoList {
  constructor() {
    this.todos = [];
    this.newTodo = '';
    this.lastId = 0;
  }

  addTodo() {
    this.lastId++;
    this.todos.push(new TodoItem(this.lastId, this.newTodo));
    this.newTodo = '';

    console.log(this.todos.length);
  }
}
```

So, I guess if I don't configure `todo/index.js` as a module Aurelia doesn't know that `todo-list.html` and `todo-list.js` are related and that's why it can't find the function `addTodo()`.

What am I doing wrong?

---

I have created a github repo with the code: https://github.com/dhAlcojor/aurelia-todo-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap all references to module names (files) in `PLATFORM.moduleName` calls.

So instead of

```
 export function configure(config) {
   config.globalResources(['./todo-list', './todo-item']);
 }
```

switch to

```
 export function configure(config) {
   config.globalResources(
     PLATFORM.moduleName('./todo-list'), 
     PLATFORM.moduleName('./todo-item');
 }
```

Also note that I got rid of wrapping the paths in an array. The framework does that for you.

Comment: Ok, I did as you told me, added the todo-item.html that was missing and it seems to work until I click on the button and I get the same error that the addTodo function doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok, I just found it. In app.html I was importing with <require from="./todo/todo-list.html"></require> and I guess Aurelia was importing JUST the HTML part of the component. I've removed the extension (.html) and now it works.

Comment: Yeah, if you add the extension, then Aurelia treats it as an HTML only custom element.